# Values not assigning correctly in 2d array

Tags: c++

I'm at my wits end, and I'm sure it's a simple mistake.  I've googled this and I've seen this similar problem presented a number of times, but my code looks similar to what I've seen so I still can't figure out what I've done wrong.

I'm working on a homework assignment for a class that asks a user for amounts of food eaten by 3 monkeys over the course of a week and then stores those entries in a 2d array.

Please forgive my horrible variable names, I'm going to change them once I break this out into different functions, but I wanted to get it running in main first.  I've tested it and my sum, average, least, and most statements work, but for some reason the data I'm entering into the array is skipping numbers or overwritting numbers (I've posted an output below as well).

When I run the code:
        #include              // for cin, cout, endl
        #include 
        #include 
        using namespace std;

```
    const int DAYS_WEEK = 7;
    const int MONKEYS = 3;


    int main()
    // main function                        
    { 
        // One dimensional array just to prove I could do it.  Also it holds         the names of the days of the week, for the cout statement below that asks for input
        string dayOfWeek[] = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri",         "Sat" };
        //2d array that will store the food eaten by each monkey as it is entered in by the user below
        double foodEaten[DAYS_WEEK][MONKEYS];
        //value to store the sum of all the food eaten by all monkeys
        double total = 0;
        //count to keep track of how many times the sum loop runs below, so         I can use it as the divisor to find the average
        int count = 0;
        //value to hold the average once found
        double average = 0;
        //value to hold the least amount of food eaten
        double least = 0;
        //value to hold the highest amount of food eaten
        double most = 0;

        //This nested loop asks for input from the user and should input the         values entered into the two dimensional array
        for ( int monkey = 0; monkey < MONKEYS; monkey++ )
        {
            for ( int day = 0; day < DAYS_WEEK; day++ )
            {
                cout << "Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey " 
                     << (monkey + 1) 
                     << " on " << dayOfWeek[day] << ": " ;  
                cin >> foodEaten[monkey][day];
                //This will double check that the user hasn't entered a         negative number and if they have throw them back into the loop
                while ( foodEaten[monkey][day] < 0 )
                {
                    cout << "Enter a non-negative amount: ";
                    cin >> foodEaten[monkey][day];
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        } 

        //This should display the table of how much food was eaten after it is all entered  
        cout << setw(6) << "Monkey" 
             << setw(5) << "Sun" 
             << setw(5) << "Mon" 
             << setw(5) << "Tue" 
             << setw(5) << "Wed" 
             << setw(5) << "Thu" 
             << setw(5) << "Fri" 
             << setw(5) << "Sat" << endl;
        for ( int monkeyLord = 0; monkeyLord <= 2; monkeyLord++)
        {
            cout << setw(6) << (monkeyLord + 1) << setw(5) <<         foodEaten[monkeyLord][0] << setw(5) << foodEaten[monkeyLord][1] << setw(5) <<         foodEaten[monkeyLord][2] << setw(5) << foodEaten[monkeyLord][3] << setw(5) <<         foodEaten[monkeyLord][4] << setw(5) << foodEaten[monkeyLord][5] << setw(5) << foodEaten[monkeyLord][6] << endl;
        }

        //This should sum all the amounts of food eaten by the monkeys
        for ( int monkeyTotal = 0; monkeyTotal <= 2; monkeyTotal ++)
        {
            for ( int dayTotal = 0; dayTotal <= 6; dayTotal ++)
            {
                total = total + foodEaten[monkeyTotal][dayTotal];
                count++;
            }
        }

        //This should find the average amount of food eaten
        average = total/count;
        cout << "The average food eaten per day by all monkeys     :" <<         setw(6) << average << " pounds" << endl;

        //This shoud find the least amount of food eaten
        least = foodEaten[0][0];
        for ( int monkeyLeast = 0; monkeyLeast <= 2; monkeyLeast ++ )
        {
            for ( int dayLeast = 0; dayLeast <= 6; dayLeast ++ )
            {
                if ( foodEaten[monkeyLeast][dayLeast] < least )
                    least = foodEaten[monkeyLeast][dayLeast];
            }
        }
        cout << "The least amount of food eaten by any monkey      :" <<         setw(6) << least << " pounds" << endl;

        //This should find the highest amount of food eaten
        most = foodEaten[0][0];
        for ( int monkeyMost = 0; monkeyMost <= 2; monkeyMost ++ )
        {
            for ( int dayMost = 0; dayMost <= 6; dayMost ++ )
            {
                if ( foodEaten[monkeyMost][dayMost] > most )
                    most = foodEaten[monkeyMost][dayMost];
            }
        }
        cout << "The largest amount of food eaten by any monkey     :" <<         setw(6) << most << " pounds" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

For some reason this is what my output looks like:

```
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 1 on Sun: 1
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 1 on Mon: 2
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 1 on Tue: 3
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 1 on Wed: 4
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 1 on Thu: 5
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 1 on Fri: 6
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 1 on Sat: 7

Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 2 on Sun: 8
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 2 on Mon: 9
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 2 on Tue: 10
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 2 on Wed: 11
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 2 on Thu: 12
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 2 on Fri: 13
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 2 on Sat: 14

Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 3 on Sun: 15
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 3 on Mon: 16
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 3 on Tue: 17
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 3 on Wed: 18
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 3 on Thu: 19
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 3 on Fri: 20
Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey 3 on Sat: 21

Monkey  Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat
     1    1    2    3    8    9   10   15
     2    8    9   10   15   16   17   18
     3   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
The average food eaten per day by all monkeys     :12.7143 pounds
The least amount of food eaten by any monkey      :     1 pounds
The largest amount of food eaten by any monkey     :    21 pounds

--------------------------------
Process exited after 19.28 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

You can see starting on Wednesday of the first row that the data is not mirroring what I entered and it happens again on the second row, but not the third.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look again at the declaration of `foodEaten`, then at how you use it. Where are the days and where are the monkeys in the declaration compared to how you use it?

Comment: Thank you, that is super helpful.  I didn't realize I was initializing it columns then rows.  I intended to initialize it as rows then columns.  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access

```
foodEaten[day][monkey]
```

not

```
foodEaten[monkey][day]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution: you should replace this line: `double foodEaten[DAYS_WEEK][MONKEYS];` with this `double foodEaten[MONKEYS][DAYS_WEEK];`

here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you are facing is that :
In effect your Array is:

> ```
>     double foodEaten[7][3]
> ```

But when you Access the elements it is in the following order:

> ```
>     foodEaten[Monkey][DayOfTheWeek]
> ```

Always ensure logical consistency in your array, i.e if your rows are Days and your columns Monkeys, ensure your iterators are also of the same type.

As the other answers have specified, using

> ```
>     foodEaten[DayOfTheWeek][Monkey]
> ```

would solve the problem.